# Zebra Stripes Procedurally

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]
Is there a way to reliably create a zebra/tiger stripe sort of pattern with nodes?

I'm hoping to apply the principle to the back of a cello [image]

Comment: This can be easily achieved with a *Wave* texture

Comment: In what manner though? I am having a hard time replicating the branching that the lines have. I did some research and apparently a Gabor Texture can do this.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Hmm ... I didn't get even closer with any of blender's texture ... any deeper explanation or direction about this black&white reference? OSL Gabor Texture goes that direction, but without chance to get spiky ends. Thank you

Comment: @vklidu Warning, blatant fake zebras below

Answer (score 4):

A vaguely similar pattern could procedurally be achieved with a *Wave* texture. Is it physically accurate? No. Is it quick and dirty? Hell yes

Set it to *Rings* mode and stretch it in one direction using a *Texture Mapping* node (here in this example the $Z$ axis).

Adjust the *Detail* to a low-ish value, and the distortion to a high value to your taste.

Lastly run it through a *Color Ramp* node set to *Constant* interpolation.

Behold, my potato zebruh with a fake pattern.

[image]

Comment: I love potato zebruh ... anyway that is what I called "far from b/w reference" :) Good tray :)